# Auto Refresh document title?

Tags: javascript, jquery, refresh, title, setinterval

I have tried many ways to have the page title automatically update every 3 seconds so the title can display how many unread messages they have.

Here is what I have tried:

```
setInterval(function() {
        document.title = "<?php echo $inboxcc; ?>";
    }, 3000);
```

and

```
$(function() {
setInterval(function() {
     $(this).attr("title", "<?php echo $inboxcc; ?>");
    }, 3000);
});
```

But none of them work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This approach won't work. Your PHP statement will execute once on the server-side, so no matter what you do in JavaScript, the title won't change more than once.

You need an AJAX-based approach, which will set the `document.title` property on success:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'new_page_title.php',
  data: {name: 'username', password: 'userpass'},
  success: function(data) { document.title = data;},
  dataType: 'text'
});
```

Now: while you certainly can tuck this code into a `setInterval` call, I would suggest that checking it every 3 seconds might get to be a bit hard on your server, and not necessary. Every 15 - 60 seconds would be gentler.

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        ...
    });
}, 30000); // milliseconds
```

Answer (score 7):

You need to refresh the data from the server each time you want fresh data, since the PHP block is only executed once per page view (on the server). Make a PHP page like this:

```
<?php
  // data.php
  // Grab the user from the session and calculate the 'unread messages' value
  $user['inboxcc'] = the_unread_messages_value;
  echo json_encode($user);
?>
```

Then pull the number dynamically like this:

```
var updater = function() {
    $.getJSON('data.php',function(jsonuser){
        document.title = jsonuser.inboxcc;
        setTimeout(updater,3000);
    });
};

setTimeout(updater,3000);
```

Note that I use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`, since you can't be sure every request will return in 3 seconds. Using `setTimeout` is better in general.

Comment: I don't really understand what to put in the data.php page

Comment: @Andy: Whatever code you are using on the original page to calculate the $inboxcc value should be in there. then put that value in a user object with the line $user['inboxcc'] = the_value;

Comment: Can't get this to work. I must be doing something wrong. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 3):

To complement @mblase75's answer (which is correct), here's a further explanation of the common misconception that you have fallen into.

---

PHP is a server-side *preprocessor* which outputs the HTML and Javascript that gets sent to your browser, then has nothing more to do with anything.

So, your PHP:

```
<?php $inboxcc = 'Title'; ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function() {
    document.title = "<?php echo $inboxcc; ?>";
}, 3000);
</script>
```

Yields the output:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function() {
    document.title = "Title";
}, 3000);
</script>
```

This is what your browser sees. And that's it.

Comment: That makes so much sense. Seems so stupid to think I actually believed it would work

Answer (score 1):

PHP block inside JavaScript can't update information for himself. You need to update title using AJAX, hidden iframe or other way. At this point your code changing `<title>` element to the same value.

Answer (score -1):

Your php code can't be interpreted in the javascript, so hide the value in a hidden input :

```
<input type="hidden" id="inboxcc" value="<?php echo $inboxcc; ?>">
```

now you can call the value in javascript:

```
setInterval(function() {
        document.title = document.getElementById('inboxcc').value;
    }, 3000);
```

Comment: Why not if this JavaScript inside `<script>` tag in HTML?

Comment: How would this work as opposed to the original code? The HTML is still static.

Comment: You're right, if input isn't refreshed, the value isn't refreshed... sorry for that reply that does not answer to the needed demand ...