# How can I change the page title

Tags: jquery, ajax, title

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery: how to change title of document during .ready()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180103/jquery-how-to-change-title-of-document-during-ready)

How to change the name of the page with jquery and ajax?

I would like to use php script and call the load function. The function returns the title to me. How do I set the page title?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/7445031/901048

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery is probably overkill for setting a title when you can just do

`document.title = 'foo';`

but if you really want to use JQuery you can do

`$("title").text("foo");`

It's probably a lot slower though, although if you're only doing it once I wouldn't worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.title("Whatever Title");
```

also i wonder if this will work:

```
$("title").html("Whatever Title");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("title").first().text("New title");
```